# In fencing, what is a point of fact?

Tags: sport, fencing

Given the [Shin A Lam controversy](http://www.google.co.uk/search?q=Shin%20A%20Lam%20controversy), I decided to look up the rules for the appeals process.

The technical rules I found on the [British Fencing website](http://www.britishfencing.com/) indicate that a point of fact can not be appealed. A couple news reports indicated that Shin A Lam's appeal was rejected on those grounds.

What is a point of fact in fencing parlance? I'm assuming it's jargon because the situation doesn't make sense when interpreted in plain English.

Comment: I don't understand *why* it doesn't make sense? *Point of fact* – Actuality, Occurrence. Whether the time ran out or was reset, the point was scored while time was on the clock. Frankly, after fencing through high school, I believe she should have remained *en garde* until the match was called, time or no.

Comment: @stslavik To a non-fencer, the term is jargon. I understand that it is analogous to normal use after your description, but as an outsider, I certainly don't see the technical implications. That said, I think the OP needs to be more explicit with the background. What is the controversy? What happened, and how is "point of fact" a relevant term?

Comment: It doesn't make sense because the timing error is an actuality and occurrence as well.

Comment: Can someone point out a specific article that discusses the term "point of fact" in context of this controversy?

Comment: http://www.statesman.com/sports/olympic-fencing-officials-say-appeal-had-no-chance-2425250.html

Answer (score 4):

Found this explanation on a fencing website:

> In foil and saber there is a rule called right of way, or priority,
>   which claims only one person may develop an attack at a time.  If both
>   fencers are touched it is up to the referee to decide which fencer
>   will be awarded the touch and why.  Difficulty arises when the
>   priority relationship between the fencers becomes confused.  Each
>   person is struggling to gain control of the attacking initiation.  If
>   sharp swords were used the truth would become apparent, but with dummy
>   tips understanding this is a subtle matter.  The rulebook has a
>   standard explanation that the referee follows when arbitrating who
>   will be awarded a touch.  However: each referee and each fencer may
>   judge events a bit differently.  When a fencer does not agree with a
>   referee’s call there is little he can do unless the referee said
>   something which was unclear, or contrary to his own logic.  It doesn’t
>   matter if both fencers think they performed in a way completely
>   opposite to the referee’s opinion - so long as the description of the
>   fencing phrase is clear the referee’s judgement is the final say in
>   the matter.
>
> In the rulebook this decision is called a point of fact.  There is no appeal for this.    However; “if the referee is ignorant of or
>   misunderstands a definite rule, or applies it in a manner contrary to
>   the Rules, an appeal on this matter may be entertained.”  (Fencing
>   Rules, 2000 Edition, t.122, t.96b)  To make an appeal the plaintiff
>   should courteously inform the director that he would like to make an
>   appeal before the bout committee.  Right then and there the bout
>   committee will decide on the issue.  The fencer making an appeal on a
>   point of fact, or anything else for this matter should use discretion,
>   since both the referee and the bout committee can penalize a fencer
>   for an Unjustified appeal t.122, Delaying the bout t.31, or Refusal to
>   obey the Referee t.82, t.84.

So if I understand it correctly, the referee judged and called the point correctly, and since he followed the rule book it can't be challenged, despite the failure of the external equipment.

Edit: Just as a note, the rule book for USA Fencing is 230 pages long. That's about the longest rule book I've ever seen.

Comment: In this particular instance, it was epee rather than foil or saber, and simultaneous touches cancel each other out.

Comment: @RobinAshe - Oh, yah, thanks for the clarification. I missed that (The epee vs foil/saber).